# accessing columns of a pandas data frame (python)

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have the following python pandas data frame ,
[image]

The column names are numerical. Let say that this data frame is **DF_data**. 
I need to access the 4th column of this data frame.

I tried

`DF_data['2.5']` , but it didnt work .

Can anyone suggest any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column names are probably `float`; try `DF_data[2.5]` (without the quote).

Comment: And in case of doubt, you can check the datatype of the column names with `print(DF_data.columns)`.